# Warn to "Save Changes" upon job preference edits

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When you change values or remove "excluded companies" when looking for a job if you navigate away without saving no warning comes in.

Please warn users to "Save" your changes before navigating away from a page, this could be a simple js alert stating "Changes have not been saved, Ok Cancel".

[image]

Twice I removed some companies and navigated away from this page only to go back to the page and see they were still there.  The save button was way at the bottom so I did not notice it, I should of been warned.

Low priority but still fixable!